# Get two or more rows within the same round that have value difference less than 20%

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have data like this:

```
# Data frame
df <- data.frame(round = factor(c(rep(1,4),rep(2,3),rep(3,4),rep(4,2))),
                 value = c(100,150,200,250,200,160,900,500,600,900,1200,100,120),
                 SE = c(1.3,1.5,0.7,2,1,2,1,1,1,0.5,0.75,20,3))
df
   round value    SE
1      1   100  1.30
2      1   150  1.50
3      1   200  0.70
4      1   250  2.00
5      2   200  1.00
6      2   160  2.00
7      2   900  1.00
8      3   500  1.00
9      3   600  1.00
10     3   900  0.50
11     3  1200  0.75
12     4   100 20.00
13     4   120  3.00
```

1. I want to get 2 or more rows within the same round that have value difference less than 20% (such as in in round 1: all row will be excluded, round 2: a row with value = 900 will be excluded, and in round 3: a  row with value = 900 and 1200 will be excluded)

What I have tried so far is:

```
library(dplyr)
 df %>%
    group_by(Round) %>%
    mutate(medians = median(value),
           deviation = abs(value - medians) * 100 / medians) %>%
    mutate(rowcounts = n()) %>%
    mutate(passORfailed = ifelse(
      rowcounts == 2,
      ifelse((max(value) - min(value)) * 100 / max(value) > 20, "failed", "pass"),
      ifelse(deviation > 20, "failed", "pass"))) %>%
    filter(passORfailed != "failed") %>%
    filter(sum(rowcounts) != 1)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 7
# Groups:   round [4]
  round value    SE medians deviation rowcounts passORfailed
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>     <dbl>     <int> <chr>       
1 1       150   1.5     175     14.3          4 pass  # -> not right     
2 1       200   0.7     175     14.3          4 pass  # -> not right       
3 2       200   1       200      0            3 pass  # -> ok      
4 2       160   2       200     20            3 pass  # -> ok      
5 3       600   1       750     20            4 pass  # -> not right (500 was excluded)       
6 3       900   0.5     750     20            4 pass  # -> not right       
7 4       100  20       110      9.09         2 pass  # -> ok      
8 4       120   3       110      9.09         2 pass  # -> ok
```

As you can see when row count is even and >3, things gone mad. The problem is when I use median, the real value that is calculated for the criteria is half (due to mean value between 2 center values). Is there anyway to adjust the code to make it possible in all situations?

2. If possible, how can I adjust the code to calculate this data within range of value +- SE ?

My apology if the question does not clear, but I've tried my best to explain.
Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach where we generate every possible pair within a round and then filter for just the rows within 20% of each other. It's a little different logic than yours, so it results in fewer matches, but maybe useful as an alternate approach if you use a different threshold, like +/- 35%, instead of +/- 20%.

```
df <- df %>% mutate(row = row_number()) 
df %>% 
  left_join(df, by = "round") %>%
  mutate(ratio = value.x / value.y) %>%
  filter(row.x != row.y,
         ratio %>% between(1/1.2, 1.2))
```

---

Here's a variation that addresses the 2nd part of the question. I calculate the value +/- SE for each and find the row pairs within each round that overlap.

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  mutate(low = value - SE,
         high = value + SE)

df %>% 
  left_join(df, by = "round") %>%
  filter(row.x != row.y,
         (high.x >= low.y & high.x <= high.y) | (low.x >= low.y & low.x <= high.y))


  round value.x SE.x row.x low.x high.x value.y SE.y row.y low.y high.y
1     4     100   20    12    80    120     120    3    13   117    123
2     4     120    3    13   117    123     100   20    12    80    120
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The first code work well with a little tweak (for my experimental research). However in the second code I expected that it will cover more matches due to the variation of SE.